# /tellraw player names in all capital letters

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using tellraw to display that "@p has won the game.":

```
/tellraw @a [{"selector":"@p","bold":true,"italic":true,"color":"dark_purple"},{"text":" HAS WON THE GAME!"}]
```

The output:

> drayson129 HAS WON THE GAME!

My question is can you make the output in full caps?:

> DRAYSON129 HAS WON THE GAME!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to modify the actual text of a JSON text element. All you can do is change its color and other formatting.

One possible option would be a resource pack that replaces all lowercase letters with uppercase ones. Obviously, this would make it impossible to have lowercase letters anywhere in the game, unless you replaced another set of characters with lowercase letters and used those instead (i.e., replace `£` with `a` and so on).

**Updated as of 1.16:**

With resource packs, [you can add custom fonts](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack#Fonts). This would let you add an "uppercase" font and use it for the player name:

```
{"selector":"@p","bold":true,"italic":true,"color":"dark_purple","font":"your_namespace:uppercase"}
```

Comment: Wow, very creative solution!

Comment: Any way to edit the command so that it's not in JSON text format? (Either change it or never have it JSON in the forst place)

Comment: @IMTIREDSHUTUP You can use the `/say` command, but it does not support formatting and always sends the message to all players. You cannot use `/tellraw` without JSON text.